# Unable to verify the first certificate; NodeJs vs Python Requests

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, python-requests

I'm trying to do an http request to stackshare.io from NodeJs:

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
   host: 'www.stackshare.io',
};

https.get(options, function (http_res) {
    var data = "";
    http_res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      data += chunk;
      console.log('data:', data)
    });

});
```

I get:

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1055:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:633:8)
```

If I change `host` to `www.google.com`, it works. Does this mean there's a problem with how stackshare is handling their SSL cert?

I found several similar (but slightly different) questions which suggested trying this:

```
var rootCas = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').create();
require('https').globalAgent.options.ca = rootCas;
```

But I still got the same error.

If I use [python requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/2.7.0/) it works:

```
import requests

print requests.get('https://stackshare.io').content
```

Is python requests somehow more tolerant with SSL certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is improperly setup and does not provide the necessary intermediate certificate to verify the trust chain. Browsers often work around such problems by trying to somehow get the missing certificates, most other applications don't. You can see this problem by looking at the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.stackshare.io) where it clearly says *"This server's certificate **chain is incomplete**. Grade capped to B."*

> If I use python requests it works: ...
>  Is python requests somehow more tolerant with SSL certificates?

Does not work for me but results instead in the same error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: ... 
>  u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed ...

It might be that you use a very old version of Python where proper certificate validation was off or that you have already imported the missing intermediate certificate into the trust store used by `requests` (which can be different than the one use by nodejs).